# Public REST API differentiating logged in vs non logged in

Tags: api, rest, security, authentication

I'm thinking about creating an auth flow. There are some apis which are public in nature (doesn't necessary require authentication but if a user is logged in, I want to be able to do personalisation) and some apis are protected.

I understand how the protected apis are to be built and what status codes to be returned there.

However, I'm uncertain about should I send the information to the clients of the public apis that the user is not logged in ? And if so what is the correct way to send this information that the api is accessible for all but the user is not logged in vs the user is logged in ?

I'm using access and refresh token based auth mechanism to protect my apis. I can think of 2 ways but not sure which is the better approach :

1. In case an access token is passed to the public api, I validate the token like a private api and return 401 in case it is invalid and 200 if it's valid. The client then attempts to generate a fresh access token, which in case the user is logged out it fails. Now the client attempts the api call without the access token and since the api is public, the logic is executed and the response is returned. 
   In this approach the client understands that he's logged out since he doesn't have a valid access token. However there are extra calls to be made each time the access token is no longer valid (which can happen a lot since the access token is short lived)
2. In case the token is invalid, I still execute the code and return the result but somehow make the client aware that the access token is no longer valid. In this approach there are no extra network calls and if the client can understand the response in a standard approach he can also know that the access token is no longer valid.
   However, in this case since the token is no longer valid I can't assume that the user is logged in and perform personalisation.

Which approach is the best and what is the recommended practice ? Or are there any other approach that I'm missing completely.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can just separate your routes in two groups, the public api, and the restricted api (only for logged users). The unique differentiation is that if you access a restricted api without credentials, it returns 401 (not authorized).

Comment: @Danizavtz the public has to be personalised if the user is logged in. How should I handle that and how should I communicate the same back to the client ? I've updated my post to add some more details. Would like if you can check those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public APIs should have 2 variants: personalized and non-personalized. Let the client software decide whether or not it wants personalization.

This doesn't necessarily mean having 2 endpoints for each call, you can add a `?personalized=true` query param. The important part is that the decision is on the client: The client has to know if it's logged in or not, and the client has to request a personalized response (and add its access token).

This means that you don't return 401 Unauthorized from a public non-personalized API variant is called, but in all other cases you return 401 if no valid token was provided.

---

There are several reasons to put the decision in the client:

First, client complexity: You don't want to bake into the API in the assumption that the client wants personalized content solely because it's logged in. Since these are public APIs, you aren't the person writing the client, and you don't know how people write their clients. For one, they might implement the access token in some central place that always sends it if it's available. They might auto refreshes the token in a flow that's separate from from the actual API calls (those will be a problem with your approach 1). For another, in most cases checking error codes is easier than checking other things (which will be a problem with your approach 2).

Second, server complexity: At some point a logged in client will want non-personalized content. That could be easy or hard to implement depending on how much of your server code makes the above assumption.

Last, flexibility: You might have a web client. You might have a mobile client. The client might not be interacting with humans at all. The client might care about efficiency more than it cares about personalization. The client might want to *avoid* the specialization but still provide a login option for another reason. You're already exposing two implementations, let the client choose.

---

Regarding the number of calls, assuming this has to do with efficiency, in almost all cases the client can easily know whether or not it has logged in. The session may time out, of course, but this case is usually not worth optimizing.

If you're planning on having many session timeouts because the personalized content contains sensitive information, then it most definitely needs to be a private API, clients need to be explicit about handling private data.

If the personalized content is not sensitive, then your login can return 2  tokens, one for private APIs and one for non-private personalized APIs, and the access token for non-private APIs can remain valid for a longer time, so that you don't have many calls regardless of how you implement personalization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. How will the session timeouts be handled ? In my case the clients won't be aware whether the access token has timed out or not and hence how will they be able to take the decision to call the personalized api or not ?

Comment: Also since the tokens that I have are short lived (about like an hour or so), this problem will be even more prevalent.

Comment: You generally look at the error code (or get an exception) when the server returns 401. If you see such an error, you know you timed out. If, at this point, you want personalized content, you have to regenerate the token somehow.

Comment: If you have so many timeouts that this case is worth optimizing, then your clients will, most of the time, not get personalized content, and your application will be inconsistent.

Comment: That's why I'm confused as to what approach to take. I was thinking that if the token is passed I'll check the sanity of it and send 401 if invalid. A client if using an api with no personalization need won't even pass the auth header. With public api and no auth header, he'll get the no personalized experience.
On the other hand with a valid token and public api he'll get a personalized experience.

Comment: Once the api sends an invalid token and 401, client tries to get the fresh access token to get the personalized experience, if the token refresh fails it calls the api without the access token to get non-personalized experience otherwise he calls with the new token to get the personalized experience.

But does this approach makes sense ?

Comment: Again, that makes the client harder to write and less flexible.I edited the answer to add more details.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.